# How to dump schema of all users defined in database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My `database.yml` looks like

```
development: &development
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: some_db
  username: admin
  password: password

temp_development:
  <<: *development
  username: another_user
  password: another_password

auth_development:
  <<: *development
  username: authority
  password: authority
```

When I run `rake db:schema:dump` it will dump all the tables created by user `admin` into `schema.rb`, how can I dump table created in another schema or created by other users like *another_user* and *authority* in `schema.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
RAILS_ENV=auth_development rake db:schema:dump
```

should do the trick (on linux). In windows imho you cannot set an environment variable and a command in one statement. So manually set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` to the environment you want, and then execute `rake db:schema:dump`.

Note: this will overwrite your current schema.rb which might or might not be what you want.